# MySQL Query Parsing using java

Tags: java, mysql

I need to parse a query which a user enters, say in a text box, and then what I need, is that I want to encrypt all the values in query leaving the query keywords. To convert it into an equivalent query that can be performed on an encrypted database.
Such as,

```
select name from employee where salary = 10000
```

I need an equivalent query as,

```
select name_enc from employee_enc where salary_enc = 10000_enc
```

where `name_enc`,`employee_enc`, `salary_enc` and `10000_enc` are the encrypted values of `name`, `employee`, `salary` and `10000`.  I need to do this in java and the the database I'm using is MySQL Server where the table `Employee` is already encrypted.

Please provide any necessary help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 10000_enc this cannot be done because 10000_enc is not a number

Comment: `SELECT name_enc FROM employee_enc WHERE salary_enc = 10000_enc`... So, the column names are encrypted?

Comment: this link is exactly what you need https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html

Comment: @ _mubeen_ for that, I'm thinking of an order prevention encryption ..which will work fine for all the integers' encryption.

Comment: @blahfunk yes, they are encrypted.

Comment: @MatheusOliveira thanks, I'll consider those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to do it manually use SQL's included encryption and encoding operations.

If you need to do it manually split your SQL query string by spaces and ignore SQL key words as you loop to encrypt. Remember to encode your cipher results with base 64 or hex to ensure data integrity.

```
private String encryptSQLQuery(String plainSQLQuery){
    StringBuilder cipherQuery = new StringBuilder();
    String plainQuery = plainSQLQuery;
    String[] splitQuery = plainQuery.split("\\s+");
    for(String queryWord : splitQuery){
       if(!isSQLKeyWord(queryWord))
           queryWord = cryptoObject.encryptAndEncode(queryWord);
       cipherQuery.append(queryWord);
       cipherQuery.append(" ");
    }
    return cipherQuery.toString();
}
```

Note that you will have to implement the `isSQLKeyWord()` and `CryptoObject.encryptAndEncode()` methods.

Comment: @ _venture_ Thank you so much ..and this _**isSQLKeyWord()**_ is the user defined function right?

Comment: @Abhishek Yes. There are quite a few keywords so I'd use a hashset to keep track of all of them.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't used it though, but it looks like it'll work. Thank you so much again.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using code from Alibaba's [Druid project](https://github.com/alibaba/druid). Although designed as a sophisticated connection pooling library, this project supports a very advanced [parser and AST](https://github.com/alibaba/druid/tree/master/src/main/java/com/alibaba/druid/sql) for ANSI SQL and non-ANSI dialects such as MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, etc. The project is open source and bears the very liberal Apache License Version 2.0.

The main entry points into this part of the library is [SQLUtils.java](https://github.com/alibaba/druid/blob/master/src/main/java/com/alibaba/druid/sql/SQLUtils.java). You can use values returned from `SQLUtils.parseStatements` to access a typed model of the statements:

```
List<SQLStatement> statements = SQLUtils.parseStatements(sql, JdbcConstants.MYSQL);
for (SQLStatement statement : statements) {
   if (statement instanceof SQLSelectStatement) {
      SQLSelectStatement createTable = (SQLSelectStatement) statement;
      // Use methods like: createTable.getSelect().getQuery().
   }
}
```